# Is creating a file-tree a built-in feature of q?

Tags: kdb, k

I've seen in .Q sources (q.k) that applying a dir-symbol to empty symbol (or to its sub-dir symbol) creates a full folders-tree, try this:

```
`:dir1 `
```

Is this behavior documented somewhere? Or is this a feature for internal use only and is subject to change?

Comment: What version? `'dir1/. OS reports: No such file or directory` for me

Comment: Try using `':dir1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because we can use key/value to file-symbol I think all other stuff works. Applying to all (`), and to the specific key works as in usual dictionary.